# LIKE operator not working in SQL (MS-Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-like

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customers
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'A%';
```

I am trying to extract all the customers whose name starts with A, but when I run this code, I get an empty query, although there are people whose name starts with A.

Comment: Access using * as wildcard character, not %: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-B2F7EF03-9085-4FFB-9829-EEF18358E931

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard in MS Access is `*`, not `%`:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM Customers
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'A*';
```

Answer (score 0):

The Access `LIKE` doesn't use `%` as a wildcard, it uses `*`. See [Like Operator](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Like-Operator-B2F7EF03-9085-4FFB-9829-EEF18358E931).